# GCP Marketplace vs Amazon Community AMI images

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, amazon-ami

Is there such concept in GCP?

I want to make my image available for the community without going through all the process of becoming a GCP partner?

Comment: Google Compute Engine Images cannot be made public. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects#limitations GCP Marketplace is the only supported method that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate my Image, then export it to Google Cloud Storage as .tar.gz file and then make it public.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image

```
gcloud beta compute images export --destination-uri gs://my-bucket/my-image.tar.gz \
    --image my-image --project my-project
```

I used beta as I was getting an error when exporting image.
Then use this link to import image from .tar.gz file and then create instance.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image